# Create an Array with New Index from Two Existing Arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I Have two arrays

```
"index":`[2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]`
```

,

and

```
"data":`[[null,null,null,63.0],
            [null,null,57.2307692308,null],
            [null,null,15.0,27.6666666667],
            [null,null,10.75,12.0],
            [null,213.0,14.6666666667,48.5],
            [null,128.0,21.25,23.0],
            [627.7647058824,113.0,36.7,19.5],
            [1201.0,132.0,523.7950819672,146.3708333333],
            [5414.1873111782,74.6666666667,668.5256916996,739.8781725888],
            [14697.0882352941,130.5,2812.1279069767,1258.0739856802],
            [11784.9188034188,1700.5353982301,4192.4097560976,1443.0708661417],
            [11256.6581196581,1218.4015748031,9908.7030075188,2055.599078341],
            [14321.3364485981,1032.9083333333,22745.9067357513,2683.6695652174],
            [16341.3267326733,491.2529411765,23721.7028571429,9549.88252149],
            [10479.1470588235,347.04,21638.5,16300.375]]}
```

`
Please suggest the best and suitable method in javascript..

```
{ x: 2004, y: null },
            { x: 2005, y: null },
            { x: 2006, y: null },
            { x: 2007, y: null },
            { x: 2008, y: 213.0 },
            { x: 2009, y: 128.0 },
            { x: 2010, y: 627.7647058824},
            { x: 2011, y: 1201.0},
            { x: 2012, y: 5414.1873111782},
            { x: 2013, y: 14697.0882352941},
            { x: 2014, y: 11784.9188034188},
            { x: 2015, y: 11256.6581196581},
            { x: 2016, y: 14321.3364485981},
            { x: 2017, y: 16341.3267326733},
            { x: 2018, y: 10479.1470588235}
```

like wise total 4 arrays for 4 elements in array 2.

Please help me with the code in javascript

Comment: You forgot to add **your** JS code. There's a huge difference from *" I do wanna convert"* and *"I want you to do this for me convert"*

Comment: Also, how's that your data is a string ` `[]` ` instead of an Array `[]`? Or it's a typo?

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand that we are not a "do your homework" site. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: So you want to use the index value for ```x``` and the *biggest* value in the arrays inside the array for ```y```? The relation between the input and output is not very clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is, you have an array which is switched index wise for mapping. You need a different approach and with `reduce`, you could iterate the outer array and the inner array and switch the indices for pushing the result object.

```js
var data = [[null, null, null, 63.0], [null, null, 57.2307692308, null], [null, null, 15.0, 27.6666666667], [null, null, 10.75, 12.0], [null, 213.0, 14.6666666667, 48.5], [null, 128.0, 21.25, 23.0], [627.7647058824, 113.0, 36.7, 19.5], [1201.0, 132.0, 523.7950819672, 146.3708333333], [5414.1873111782, 74.6666666667, 668.5256916996, 739.8781725888], [14697.0882352941, 130.5, 2812.1279069767, 1258.0739856802], [11784.9188034188, 1700.5353982301, 4192.4097560976, 1443.0708661417], [11256.6581196581, 1218.4015748031, 9908.7030075188, 2055.599078341], [14321.3364485981, 1032.9083333333, 22745.9067357513, 2683.6695652174], [16341.3267326733, 491.2529411765, 23721.7028571429, 9549.88252149], [10479.1470588235, 347.04, 21638.5, 16300.375]],
    index = [2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
    result = data.reduce((r, a, i) =>
        (a.forEach((y, j) => (r[j] = r[j] || []).push({ x: index[i], y })), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the funcion `reduce` for this, this will allow you to iterate into one array and have easier control on the new array.

Read the docs on how to use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce .

Hope this helps!

Comment: Reduce on strings?

Comment: He said, from two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think my js tools can help you
https://github.com/wm123450405/linqjs

```js
let index = [2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018];
let data = [[null,null,null,63.0],[null,null,57.2307692308,null],[null,null,15.0,27.6666666667],[null,null,10.75,12.0],[null,213.0,14.6666666667,48.5],[null,128.0,21.25,23.0],[627.7647058824,113.0,36.7,19.5],[1201.0,132.0,523.7950819672,146.3708333333],[5414.1873111782,74.6666666667,668.5256916996,739.8781725888],[14697.0882352941,130.5,2812.1279069767,1258.0739856802],[11784.9188034188,1700.5353982301,4192.4097560976,1443.0708661417],[11256.6581196581,1218.4015748031,9908.7030075188,2055.599078341],[14321.3364485981,1032.9083333333,22745.9067357513,2683.6695652174],[16341.3267326733,491.2529411765,23721.7028571429,9549.88252149],[10479.1470588235,347.04,21638.5,16300.375]];

console.log(index.asEnumerable().zip(data, (i, d) => ({ x: i, y: d.asEnumerable().max() })).toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://wm123450405.github.io/linqjs/libs/linq-js.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can use Array.prototype.map

```js
let index = [2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018];
let data = [[null,null,null,63.0],[null,null,57.2307692308,null],[null,null,15.0,27.6666666667],[null,null,10.75,12.0],[null,213.0,14.6666666667,48.5],[null,128.0,21.25,23.0],[627.7647058824,113.0,36.7,19.5],[1201.0,132.0,523.7950819672,146.3708333333],[5414.1873111782,74.6666666667,668.5256916996,739.8781725888],[14697.0882352941,130.5,2812.1279069767,1258.0739856802],[11784.9188034188,1700.5353982301,4192.4097560976,1443.0708661417],[11256.6581196581,1218.4015748031,9908.7030075188,2055.599078341],[14321.3364485981,1032.9083333333,22745.9067357513,2683.6695652174],[16341.3267326733,491.2529411765,23721.7028571429,9549.88252149],[10479.1470588235,347.04,21638.5,16300.375]];

console.log(index.map((x, i) => ({ x, y: Math.max(...data[i]) })));
```